# VBA: How to read a Hindi word

Tags: vba, excel

vb macros - I want to read a Hindi word which is in Excel cell and displays in message box by writing macros.

I tried with an English word that displays in the message box but not the Hindi word.

Comment: Please add some examples and more details ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, this is a tricky one.

I Googled *namaste in hindi*. Google gave me translation of namaste to नमस्ते. That was copied to Excel's A1 cell.

In Excel VBA, create a module and type the following:

```
#If VBA7 Then
Public Declare PtrSafe Function MessageBoxU Lib "user32" Alias "MessageBoxW" _
    (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
     ByVal lpText As LongPtr, _
     ByVal lpCaption As LongPtr, _
     ByVal wType As Long) As Long
#Else
Public Declare Function MessageBoxU Lib "user32" Alias "MessageBoxW" _
    (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
     ByVal lpText As Long, _
     ByVal lpCaption As Long, _
     ByVal wType As Long) As Long
#End If

Sub DisplayNamaste()
    Dim Info As String
    Info = Range("A1").Value
    MessageBoxU 0, StrPtr(Info), StrPtr("Here's the message"), 0
End Sub
```

You will see a message box pop up with नमस्ते in it. The text may look small. Note that MsgBox in VBA does not support Unicode and therefore you won't be able to display, using MsgBox, information in variety of languages.

**Credit: [Renaud Bompuis's blog](http://blog.nkadesign.com/2013/vba-unicode-strings-and-the-windows-api/)**